# How to store/encode URL with percentage % in config file?

Tags: python, url, config, encode

I'm trying to manage my data by storing it under config file. I ran into issue while I was creating my file that the URL contains '%20' and it returned the following error msg:

```
 raise ValueError("invalid interpolation syntax in %r at "
```

Here is an example of my URL format (a lil bit context here: I'm using it to get API request)

```
https://api.abc.com/a0/asaknfalhiasfna/Test%20Name?failed=why+why+why
```

And this is what I had in my config.py

```
import configparser
config = configparser.ConfigParser()

config['ClientProd'] = {'url': 'https://api.abc.com/a0/asaknfalhiasfna/Test%20Name?failed=why+why+why',
'response': 'id'}


with open('conf.ini', 'w') as configfile:
    config.write(configfile)
```

Here is the reference on what I'm trying to achieve: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48572494/structuring-api-calls-in-python)
How can I encode the **%20** in the URL here? Any help would be greatly appreciate it, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can escape with another `%` proceeding the problematic one.

```py
config['ClientProd'] = {'url': 'https://api.abc.com/a0/asaknfalhiasfna/Test%%20Name?failed=why+why+why',
'response': 'id'}
```

Source:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#interpolation-of-values

Answer (score 0):

If your ini file don't use interpolation, the easiest way is to disable interpolatin in the construction:

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser(interpolation=None )
```